# React js regex find all words beginning and ending with __

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, file

I have a txt file like this:

```
Io sottoscritto/a __NOME__
nato a __CITTA_NASCITA__(__SIGLA_CITTA_NASCITA__) il __DATA_NASCITA__
residente a __RESIDENZA__   in via __VIA_RESIDENZA__    n __NUMERO_RESIDENZA__.
```

I have to make sure that when user loads the file in question, an array is created containing all the words starting with __ and ending with __, of the type `__NAME__`

I managed to do this the problem that the regex also finds me the following words together: `["__CITTA_NASCITA__(__SIGLA_CITTA_NASCITA__)", "__NUMERO_RESIDENZA__."]`

In the first case the two words must be separated.

In the second case there must be no end point.

Result:

`["__CITTA_NASCITA__", "__SIGLA_CITTA_NASCITA__", "__NUMERO_RESIDENZA__"]`

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

link: https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-butterfly-ey8og?file=/src/App.js

```js
export default function App() {
  const showFile = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async (e) => {
      const text = e.target.result;
      const row = text.split("\n");
      let array = [];
      row.map((el) =>
        el.split(" ").map((ul) => {
          var reg = /^__[A-Za-z]*__/;
          if (reg.test(ul)) {
            console.log(ul);
            array.push(ul);
          }
        })
      );
      console.log(array);
    };
    reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => showFile(e)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You could match all the occurrences in the file `__[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*__` https://regex101.com/r/oUmIJQ/1

Comment: The problem is the all text is split with line feed into lines and then each line is split with a space and the items are checked with your regex (that does not even chek if the pattern matches the entire "token". The punctuation and more can get into the resulting array this way. See my answer how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fix the code by extracting all matches directly from the `text` variable:

```js
 const reg = /__[A-Z_]+__/ig;

  const showFile = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async (e) => {
      const text = e.target.result;
      let array = text.match(reg);
      setArray(array);
    };
    reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
  };
```

Note if you only allow a single underscore between `__` delimiters, you will need to use the

```js
const reg = /__[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*__/ig;
```

Also, see the `row` and `row.map(...)` code parts are unnecessary here.

Comment: What do you mean by: `const reg = /__[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*__/ig;`;
When should it be used?

Comment: @Paul Just below `export default function App() {`. Replace `showFile` with my version. Replace your `showFile` with all my code snippet.

Comment: @Paul Any problem with that? Shall I copy the whole code from your code demo with my fix implemented?

Comment: I'm not able to figure out what the difference between using this:
`/__[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*__/ig`
is
`/__[A-Z_]+__/ig`

Comment: @Paul See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/JNZV5y/3/) vs. [this one](https://regex101.com/r/JNZV5y/4/). `/__[A-Z_]+__/ig` matches `__DATA_NASCITA____RESIDENZA__` as a single entity.

Answer (score 0):

I see the code and run the example on sandbox
I changed the regex a little to "**[A-Za-z_]+?**" this it is more accurate now and works accordingly the way you wanted.

![output] [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey7pt.png)

Comment: This only works in the regex tester. In the code, the output is not the expected one because of additional preprocessing OP uses.